# After publishing an app, how do you find the public URL to give to your end users?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have published my app in Google App Maker, however when I share the normal "share" link it gives end users the ability to edit the app instead of using the app.

Where do I find the public version of the app I just published?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Settings
2. Select Deployments tab
3. Click or copy deployment link

[image]

**Note:** The URL is not really public. You can share the app only within your domain at your best.