# Google App Maker console

Tags: google-app-maker

Just started using App Maker and I'm still getting the console displayed at the bottom of the window when I publish an app. How do I hide this please?

Answer (score 2):

Do not mess Preview and Publish. By default your **Preview** Deployment always shows AM console(you always see Preview Deployment when you click Preview button). To open one of your **published** deployments you need to navigate to Settings -> Deployment and click correspondent deployemnt link. You can find some pics in this answer:

[After publishing an app, how do you find the public URL to give to your end users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136328/after-publishing-an-app-how-do-you-find-the-public-url-to-give-to-your-end-user/44138941#44138941)

**Note:** you can always show/hide console by toggling this URL parameter(in browser address bar):

```
?console=1
```